# How to calculate the sum of a single row while updating them

Tags: php, mysql

```
Id  Account_name       Date         Debit   Credit
1   expense           2014-05-03     80      100
3   machinery         2014-05-03     45       0 
4   prepaid           2014-05-03     50       40
5   food              2014-05-03     50       60
6   a/p               2014-05-03     0        0 
7   rent_expense      2014-05-04     0        0
8   laundry_revenue   2014-05-04     0        0
9   accrued_revenue   2014-05-04     0        0
10  unearned_revenue  2014-05-04     0        0
11  safir             2014-05-04     0        0
12  car_rent          2014-05-04     50       80    
13  revenue           2014-05-05     40      40
```

In this table if I update a row how then can I find debit and credit individually of each row like expense, machinery etc…

```
INSERT INTO transaction (account_name,dates,debit,credit)
VALUES('$account_name',curdate(),0+$debit,0+$credit)
ON duplicate KEY
UPDATE debit=VALUES(debit),credit=VALUES(credit)
```

Comment: Do you want to accomplish that in PHP or mysql? Also, are debit and credit INTs, Floats, Doubles, strings or what?

Comment: Do you want to add the new debit and credit to the existing value when updating?

Comment: yes that it what i want  @Barmar?

Comment: @briosheje in php and mysql the values are in INTs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to the column name in the `UPDATE` clause, it accesses the old value in the row.

```
INSERT INTO transaction (account_name,dates,debit,credit)
VALUES('$account_name',curdate(),0+$debit,0+$credit)
ON duplicate KEY
UPDATE debit = debit + VALUES(debit), credit = credit + VALUES(credit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the var $row from the statement, then use the math equation below:

```
$total=$row['debit']+$row['credit'];
```